# What is the mathematical interpretation of random variable equation?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Following is the equation:
$$X = Y + Z.$$
$X, Y, Z$ are random variables. This is a random variable equation. What is the meaning of this equation? Does it mean that if you take any value of $Y$ and any value of $Z$, it should equal $X$? Or does it mean that when $Y$ and $Z$ are added, then $Y+Z$ will have same distribution as $X$?

Comment: It is pretty common to add random variables together to get a new random variable.  For example, the binomial distribution is a sum of independent Bernoulli trials.  So I think your second interpretation is correct.

Comment: The equation $X=Y+Z$ usually means $X$  is a random variable defined as the sum of $Y$ and $Z$.  In other contexts it may mean that a particular value of $X$ is the sum of a particular value  of $Y+Z$.and you might ask what is the probability of such an equality.  As you can see it all depends on context.

Comment: It means that the random result $X$ equals the sum of the random results $Y$ and $Z.$

Comment: It does not simply mean that $X$ and $Y + Z$ have the same distribution. It means that $X$ *is* $Y + Z$.

Comment: To demonstrate @littleO's point, let Y and Z be uniform over $(0, 1)$. Then their sum Z follows a triangle distribution over $(0, 2)$.

Comment: For example, let $Y$ be the number of boys in a kindergarden class, $Z$ the number of girls, and $X$ the total number of students.  So $X=Y+Z$, and yet all three quantities $(X,Y,Z)$ form a random vector.

Comment: @herbsteinberg "As you can see it all depends on context" No it does not. Why mislead the OP?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. It give different perspectives to the question...

Comment: @Shiran Why did you accept a wrong answer? FYI, in mathematics, quite a few points are not matters of "perspective" but "right" or "wrong".

Comment: @Did Can u pls elaborate more on your last point... i really appreciate if you do..

Comment: ?? Why should I "elaborate" on anything? You *accepted* an answer, this can only mean that, to you, the case is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Random variables are defined as measurable functions from a probability space $\Omega$ into some target space.  Without any further context, I interpret that equality as an equality of functions, e.g. $X(\omega) = Y(\omega) + Z(\omega)$ for every $\omega \in \Omega$.  Quite often in probability, we only care about equality on a set of measure 1, and it is common to see $X = Y+Z$ a.s. where a.s. is an abbreviation for almost surely, which means that the functions $X$ and $Y+Z$ might differ on a tiny set of measure 0, but we don't care.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation...